# Connection reset to SQL Server when using SSH Tunnel

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, connectivity, dbeaver, ssh

I am trying to connect to an MS SQL Server database through DBeaver via an SSH tunnel but am getting the following error message when I "Test Connection...":

> I/O Error: Connection reset
>         java.net.SocketException : Connection reset

[image]

If I set the `Keep-Alive interval` to anything other than 0, the error becomes the following:

```
Can't initialize tunnel
  Cannot establish tunnel
    com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: timeout in waiting for rekeying process.
```

[image]

Looking at the debug log, `~/.dbeaver4/.metadata/dbeaver-debug.log`, I see that the connection was initially successful but later reset. I don't believe it is a problem in my connection settings configuration (my colleages with Mac's connected successfully using the same settings)

Here's an excerpt from the `dbeaver-debug.log`:

```
2017-06-26 15:01:35.354 - Instantiate SSH tunnel
2017-06-26 15:01:35.355 - Connect to tunnel host
2017-06-26 15:01:35.356 - SSH INFO: Connecting to jdms.dssg.io port 22
2017-06-26 15:01:35.480 - SSH INFO: Connection established
.
.
.
2017-06-26 15:01:35.953 - SSH INFO: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
2017-06-26 15:01:36.083 - Connection failed (mssql-hashhashhash-hashhashhash)
2017-06-26 15:01:36.085 - SSH INFO: Disconnecting from jdms.dssg.io port 22
2017-06-26 15:01:36.086 - SSH INFO: Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed
2017-06-26 15:01:36.135 - org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCConnectException: I/O Error: Connection reset
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBCConnectException: I/O Error: Connection reset
.
.
.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Connection reset
.
.
.
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Could this be a Linux specific issue?

How else can I debug my problem?

I am using DBeaver 4.0.8 to connect to a MS SQL Server database using the jTDS driver, in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: are you sure it is server_name.team_name.com and not the other way round `team_name.server_name.com`?

Comment: @Jakuje you are right but that filler-text is not meaningful here (it is correct in my true configuration)

Comment: If your coworker can connect to the exact same server with the exact same config using the exact same version of the app then it's probably related to your specific machine.  Do you have some kind of layer 7 firewall, specific outbound firewalls, or any network protection/AV programs that might be causing an issue?  Can you start with minimal daemons running?

Comment: It could be proxy issues. Not sure, but you can try this config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76948786/6909832

Answer (score 1):

Try the [JDBC driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774) or [ODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server)([Install/Config Info per platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server)) supplied by Microsoft for Linux clients.  I've found that I'm often more successful when using the drivers provided by the vendor than those that are included with the product (e.g. in this case DBeaver).  I would think all the other settings remain the same, just swap out the driver url to point the MS supplied driver instead.